# Веб-разработка

Tags: вёрстка, дизайн

Здравствуйте. Нас пару студентов программистов и мы думаем заняться веб-разработкой. С написанием практически любого функционала проблем не возникает. Но вот дизайн... Сможем ли мы обойтись скаченными шаблонами страниц, кое-где своими силами или все же лучше найти верстальщика? В-общем вопрос в том, сложно ли научиться делать дизайн страниц и верстать или лучше пока за это не браться, а отдать эту работу веб-дизайнерам?

Comment: Это зависит от сложности дизайна. Если страницы предполагают использование html5, css3, SASS, SCSS, LESS и прочих модных штучек, то лучше предоставить это дело верстальщику. Иначе времени на это может уйти много.

Comment: Я например, создаю проекты исключительно сам. Никаких проблем.

Comment: @Lucky, впринципе проблем с фреймворками не возникает, ибо это тоже программирование (JQuery и даже ExtJS). А вот сделать красивый дизайн мне представляется сложным. Хотя если честно особо не пытался. Работал сейчас в конторе оффициально и дизайн от меня не требовался. Но мало платили и пришлось уйти. Вот решили без посредников на фрилансе брать проекты и делать. Все программисты и дизайн немножко пугает)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На начальном этапе скачанные шаблоны - это хорошо, но когда потребуется добавить функционал в макет + красивый дизайн(и как правильно подметили уникальный) останется либо скаченный шаблон переписывать, либо отдать это на аутсорс, либо с нуля писать свой.

По-моему, если у вас нет проблем с функционалом серверной части, то особых проблем не должно быть и с версткой на *базовом уровне*. Это в идеале конечно человек-комбайн, который и программирует и верстает. В идеале для российских веб-студий, но лучше сразу выделить отдельных людей под свои отдельные нужды, либо учиться самим, благо это не сложно. Да, есть свои камни в кроссбраузерной верскте, адаптивности и прочем, но если проблем нет, то учитесь сами, тем более, как вы написали - вы студенты, соответственно на аутсорс, я так понимаю средств нет.

Comment: @DroidAlex, спасибо за ответ. Думаю будем пробовать делать сами. Даже верстку сами сделаем, но вот сделать ее красиво... Будем учиться) Благо время еще есть) Правда думали на фрилансе попроще будет проекты искать. За слишком сложные пока побаиваемся браться. Но это уже другая тема.

Answer (score 3):

Можно посмотреть в сторону фронтенд-фреймворка [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) и обойтись своими силами.

Comment: @Khvorostin, спасибо. Обязательно присмотримся.

Answer (score 2):

Фреймворкеры хороши для быстрого и несложного прототипирования, но как только появится потребность в эксклюзивном дизайне или необычной правке текущего, придётся обращаться к верстальщикам и дизайнерам.

Вёрстке научиться не так сложно как дизайну, поскольку рисовать не всем дано, нужно иметь творческую жилку и уметь использовать её применительно к веб-дизайну.

Comment: Везде есть свои подводные камни. А в верстке их хоть отбавляй.

Comment: @Gena Tsarinny, благо найти примеры красивостей, шаблоны и пр. сейчас не такая проблема) А если уж возникают, то благо есть такие добрые форумы и их пользователи.